# when I add react-router-dom on my project , I see this error

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

Failed to compile.

```
Error in ./~/react-router-dom/dist/umd/react-router-dom.development.js
Module parse failed: /home/mehmet/Desktop/react/Login/form/node_modules/react-router-dom/dist/umd/react-router-dom.development.js Unexpected token (565:79)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (565:79)
 @ ./~/react-router-dom/dist/main.js 18:19-67
```

I was looked and try  all answer at internet

Comment: Please include more detail. Are you using a framework? If yes, which one are you using? Have you imported it somewhere? As much as possible.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I received exactly the same error if I installed the application via: npx create-react-app. And then installed: npm install react-router-dom. If this is the case, keep in mind that create-react-app has not been updated since 2022 and is probably not supported. The problem was that "react-scripts" was installing an old version. But even if you specify a new version in package.json, it will be an application with vulnerabilities.
Install the application via vite. I found a good description of how to do this [here](https://scrimba.com/articles/create-react-app-with-vite/).